# Modify Wordpress comment date output

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm using the default WordPress comment system and in my comment template, I use

```
<?php wp_list_comments() ?>
```

to generate the comments and I was wondering how I can modify the comment date? Currently, it displays the full date as such *February 11, 2014 at 6:27 am*. After looking at the [WordPress codec](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/) it doesn't seem like I can modify the date format through the `wp_list_comments` args.

How can I modify the date format output?

Comment: What do you mean adjust it? Just change the date format?

Comment: @nCore Yes, I want to change the date format. I don't like it showing the exact time will probably do something just like the month.

Comment: have a look at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_date

Comment: Yes, but when you use the wp_list_comments it generates the comment code so you can't adjust the date with that.

Comment: Oh right, then you'd need to specify whatever formatting you'd need. http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_date. That's pretty much all how to format date and use it on comments

Comment: I have the formatting for the date set in my wordpress settings but I would like set a different format for just the comments

Comment: Yeah I figured there is one in the settings but that will affect the rest of the dates on your website. However if you specify the format only for comments like the codex above, see how it goes if its not something you need then I guess custom function will do the trick.

Comment: How would I do a function to adjust the date comment?

Comment: So the above links didn't help you?

Comment: I'm still learning php and while I can adjust things in wordpress writing a function to change something is a little out of my skill level right now.

Comment: How exactly do you want to adjust the date? can you give an example of how you want it.

Comment: Currently the date is  November 6, 2010 12:50 am and I would prefer to just have  November 6, 2010, which would be F j, Y in the php I just don't know how to hook into the comments to adjust just the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:
1. You can try to modify the wordpress core file wp-includes/comment-template.php. to modify the date format  you wish to have(This might seem easier but i won't suggest you to modify the core files )
2. you can create a custom callback function to display your comment as below:
You would call the function

now you can create your custom function my_custom_comment in your function.php file and it will simply replace the default listing with your custom listing format.

Now create a function named my_custom_comment in your function.php and modify the date format

For more details on wp_list_comment take a look at [wp_list_comment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments))

```
function my_custom_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

if ( 'div' == $args['style'] ) {
    $tag = 'div';
    $add_below = 'comment';
} else {
    $tag = 'li';
    $add_below = 'div-comment';
}
?>
<<?php echo $tag ?> <?php comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ) ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
<?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
<div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="comment-author vcard">
<?php if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
<?php printf( __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>' ), get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
</div>
<?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
    <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></em>
    <br />
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
    <?php
        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
        printf( __('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a><?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)' ), '  ', '' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php comment_text(); ?>

<div class="reply">
<?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'add_below' => $add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function under comment find these:

```
sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
```

or

```
printf( __('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time())
```

then remove the %2$s and , get_comment_time() something like these:

```
sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_comment_date() )
```

or

```
printf( __('%1$s'), get_comment_date())
```

again if you want to modify the date use the reference below:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

usage:
get_comment_date('D, F j')

I hope this is something you like.

Comment: I don't have those in my functions as my entire theme is custom coded that I created

Comment: Yay! so is mine but im using HTML5 Blank which has function.php but anyway that's how you remove the time stamp: best get that function if you want to modify the date. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Using the WordPress Codec documentation, you add a **callback** function as an argument to `wp_list_comments`.

```
<?php
    wp_list_comments( array(
        'style'       => 'ul',
        'callback'  =>  'custom_comment_template'
    ));
?>
```

Copy comment template from *wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php.* And modify this section to suit your need. You can use the [DATE and TIME Formatting](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/) for WordPress here.

```
 function custom_comment_template(){
 // Codes you have copies from wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php
 // Or any design you want to use. You can use the hooks and filters
 // from wp-includes/comment-template.php like 
    get_comment_author_link, get_comment_author

 <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment, $args ) ); ?>">
    <?php
     /* translators: 1: Comment date, 2: Comment time. */
     printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s' ), get_comment_date( '', $comment ), get_comment_time() );
            ?>
  </a>
  <?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)' ), '&nbsp;&nbsp;', '' ); ?>
 </div>
 }
```